# $this->data empty after performing an ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I am implementing a function populatig a select box using data from another select box.

```
//views/users/ajax.ctp
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        data:"arr=" + result,
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById(child).innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
```

As you can see from the code above the data passed by the call should be accessible in the getSectors() function under the `data` variable:

```
//controllers/users_controller.php
function getSectors() {
    $this->set('data', $this->data);
    $this->render('/users/ajax_data');
}
```

In the corresponding view I try to see the content of the data passed:

```
//views/users/ajax_data.ctp
<?php var_dump($data); ?>
```

The $data is null.

Debugging that in Firebug shows that the call is invoked properly (`status 200 ok`) and that the XMLHttpRequest contains parameters and values.

Do you have any suggestions what could be possibly wrong?

Comment: what url do you use in your ajax call... url?

Comment: In firebug, does the response contain the expected html?

Comment: @barts getSectors, and yes firebug outputs expected html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for Cake to populate the `$this->data` variable, the data being send needs to follow the format `data[Model][field]`, or at least be part of the `data[..]` array. If it's plainly named `arr`, Cake won't put it in the `$this->data` variable.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning `$this->params`

Comment: How can I access the data if I want to name it as `arr` ?